# Lazy Loading Vue Components with Webpack 2

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

I am looking to try **lazy loading** with `webpack`. I split my app by routes, and every route has required component:

```
const Home = resolve => {  
    require.ensure([ "../components/Home/Home.vue" ], () => {
        resolve(require("../components/Home/Home.vue"));
    });
};
```

I got my chunks in separate folders every time I go to different route:
`bundle1.js, bundle2.js, bundle3.js` an on for every component in routes.

Now I don't know how can I load only bundle I need for that route? If I put `bundle.js` in **index.html** it will load the whole bundle, but I just want to load the only bundle that I need for that route?

```
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- how to auto inject build files here?? -->
  </body>
```

There is section for [Lazy Loading](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html) for Vue components. I did that and I get chunks of bundle files. **But I don't know what is proper way to include them and load it**.

Any help is appreciate. Thanks

Comment: are you using vue-cli with webpack?

Comment: No, I want to setup project by myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a documentation about how to implement that here:

1. https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html
2. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components

Comment: The user knows where to find said documentation, they literally reference one of your links.

Answer (score 0):

> We can implement the lazy loading easily, thanks to an upcoming JavaScript feature, dynamic imports, that webpack supports.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

function loadView(view) {
  return () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "view-[request]" */ `@/views/${view}.vue`)
}

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: loadView('Home')
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: loadView('About')
    }
  ]
})
```

Of course this answer was taken from [this article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/lazy-loading-vue-cli-3-webpack/) and i suggest you to read it.